# Box pop up on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to figure out how I might go about adding a div at the bottom of a page that nicely scrolls up when you reach the bottom of the page. I want it hidden until I reach that div at the bottom, and i want it to nicely scroll up when I reach it, and nicely scroll back down when I scroll back up.

This is what I'm starting with:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
   if( $(document).scrollTop() >  ) {
      $('#signup').show();
   } else {
      $('#signup').hide();
   }
});
```

```css
html { height: 2000px; } /* create a scrollbar for demo purposes */

#signup {
    position: fixed;
    top: 200px;
    right: 50px;
    display: none;
  background-color:purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="signup">Sign up!</div>
```

but I can't really seem to figure out where to go from here, and this isn't even doing much. TIA

[image]

Comment: You actually don't need javascript for this. You can do position absolute on your signup div and on the parent maybe body{position:relative;"}. This way it is always visible when you scroll down. Scrolling up will hide the div anyway.

Comment: Right - but I want it to animate up and down. Sort of like a pop-up window but in a less invasive way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to check if the `scrollvalue` + `window height` are the same of the `document`; then two options to animate the box `animate()` with Jquery or use `transition` on CSS:

Check this example snippet:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    $('#signup').addClass('show')
  } else {
    $('#signup').removeClass('show')
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
/* create a scrollbar for demo purposes */

#signup {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:100;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: purple;
  transition: bottom .5s linear;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center
}
#signup.show {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="signup">Sign up!</div>
```

Comment: Hi DaniP - this worked perfect.
Only thing is that it overlaps my footer.

Any ideas how to avoid this? I attached an image in my original post for reference.

Comment: @becca and wich is the expected behavior? push up all body? or go in front of all ?

Comment: I would like it to be on top / in front of everything.

Comment: @becca just need to add a higher value for `z-index` on the CSS ... check edited code

Comment: Awesome thanks!

One last question - any ideas how you might add an 'x' in the corner where someone could close it if they wanted to?

Comment: @becca check this quick example https://jsfiddle.net/armzgfcq/ ... later you can replace that span with an a tag and make a beatifull x with pseudo-elements, but to show you quick click that **X**

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/armzgfcq/2/
See there - I am having a problem because my boostrap buttons contain spans.
Any fix ideas?

Comment: @becca then use an a tag and assign an special classname http://www.bootply.com/Oc3jNX305W

Comment: I tried that as well - it seems to be just resetting the page in this instance which isn't what i'd like it to do. I'd like it to just shut that pop up div and remain at the bottom of the page. Any ideas? I can post another question if stuck.

Comment: @becca am I guess it's beacuse you are using an a tag with # href my mistake making the demo check this new one http://www.bootply.com/qRe8RQPYkt